# Consuming WCF Service with DataContract

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I do have a simple WCF service in which If I put the method with simple Data Type then I can access that service in the MVC project which is in same Solution. But if I change the Data Type of the Service method even to array or list of string or any other simple Data Type, I cannot access the service. Do I need to make any config changes.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Property
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PropertyPost { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PropertyType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string DealType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    }
```

I actually want to return the List from the WCF service for which I have created the Datacontract, but it is not working even with simple List Type.
Do we need to specify anything in Service like WebInvoke?
Can any one help?

Comment: Can you post the DataContract class?

Comment: If it is "not working", I suggest changing it, so it "works" (tm). If you need help doing this, maybe you should start by giving a precise description of the problem. That includes AT LEAST the error messages and the code that produce those messages.

Comment: Do we need to specify anything in Service like WebInvoke??

Comment: Return list  / array from WCF service works. If you need some more help - please, consider to update your question with more code / error details.

Comment: @Bhushan WebInvoke shouldn't have anything to do with it.  You should be able to access arrays in almost the same way -- what error(s) / problem(s) are you seeing?

Comment: I tried same with VS 2010 and MVC3 which is working fine with DataContract too. I'm facing problem if I do it in VS 2012 with MVC4. If I return string then it works but if I change the return type to list and update the service reference in MVC project, I didn't get the serviceClass itself for creating the object.